# Sorting a copy of a list in python gone wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, copy

I was trying to copy a list to sort the copy but for some reason it sorted the original list as well.
Here is the code part. I use the debugger to figure out what happened after the sort function.

```
p = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
copy = p
```

now according to debugger, (copy = [7,1,5,3,6,4])
then I do

```
copy.sort(reverse = True)
```

But now both copy and p = [7,6,5,4,3,1]
I found the solution by copy = p.copy(). But I don't understand why original list also changed.

Comment: `copy = p` *doesn't copy anything, assignment never copies*. You should check out the following for getting a handle on Python's semantics with regards to assignment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

if you want a copy, you have to explicitly request one. List objects (and many other built-in objects)  have a `.copy` method, so `copy = p.copy()` would work, or another common idiom is taking a "full slice", `copy = p[:]`, note, both of these will make shallow copies, but that shouldn't matter in your sorting case

Answer (score 2):

If you want a second variable to be a unique copy of another list, you can call its `copy` method.

For example:

```
>>> a=[3,2,1]
>>> b=a.copy()
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[3, 2, 1]
```

Otherwise if you just do `b = a` , then `b` is just a reference to `a`, both pointing to the same object.

---

By the way, the idiomatic way to sort a list, when it doesn't have to be in-place, is to use `sorted`, i.e.

```py
>>> a=[3,2,1]
# this:
>>> b=a.copy()
>>> b.sort()
# ..is equivalent to:
>>> b=sorted(a)
```

`.sort()` is useful whenever you want to avoid creating a copy of the list you need sorted, since you will only ever be dealing with the original list once its items are in order.

Comment: Worth noting, `sorted` takes *any arbitrary iterable* and returns a list